# Android ListView in Activity

Tags: android, android-listview

My layout is like this

```
Title Layout
Listview
BottomLayout.
```

I have an 150 item which i have custom layout which i want to add in listview.
So my main problem is i want to add slowly slowly one by one that customlayouts in listview.
So whenever the first screen is displayed i want load 10 items from server and add it to listview.then onscroll down i want to load the remaining 10 items from 150 cutom layouts.
So how can I do this activity?

Comment: Pls. accept some more questions to increase the chance of people helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement is basically similar to the Android Market mobile application where you display "n" no of list times on the screen .

Consider "n" items as 10 . Now when the user scrolls to the 10 th item of the screen , you are starting a progressdialog & fetching the next set of 10 items from the server & updating the list . So currently , the list contains 20 items. This should contain till all the items are loaded from the server.

I have implemented the above requirement. Basically its like a pagination implementation , but the list items are add to the same screen downwards.

I have created a class which extends BaseAdapter. I wrote the code , which checks the last item of the list . When I go to the last item , I check whether the next page is available or not . Based on that , a hit the server.